# Geometry, Circles and Chords

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, power-of-the-point

Two circles intersect at points $A$ and $B$. Chords $AC$ and $AD$ are drawn through the point $A$. Prove that $AC^2\cdot BD=AD^2\cdot BC$.

So, most probably, we'll use Power of point on $A$ and $B$, giving $AC^2=AB \cdot BC$ and $AD^2=AB \cdot BD$. So, finally, we get the desired result. Is this solution proper?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Is there something that restricts where C & D are? Because in the statement of the problem it seems like they can be anywhere. If C can be arbitrarily close to A, and D can be arbitrarily close to B, then the chords AC and BD can be made arbitrarily close to zero, while AD and BC will be approximately the same length as AB.

Comment: I believe CD is a line segment which passes through A. A single line.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about how you're applying the power of a point? Since $A$ and $B$ are on the circles, their powers with respect to those circles are zero.

Comment: @Blue Yup. Since their powers are zero, they are all equal, right?

Comment: @Sen47: None of the relations you show involve the powers of $A$ or $B$. It's not clear to me how those relations arise. For $AB\cdot BC$ to be a power calculation, $A$, $B$, $C$ must be collinear; likewise, for $AB\cdot BD$ to be a power calculation requires $A$, $B$, $D$ are collinear. $AC^2$ and $AD^2$ look like power calculations along tangent segments. None of this makes any sense.

Comment: Oh, okay. I'll try to upload another solution soon. Thanks for pointing that out, sir.

Comment: If you can, provide an image of the configuration as you see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  chords $AC$ and $AD$ are tangents to another circles, so $$\Delta ABC\sim \Delta DBA, $$ which gives
$$\frac{AB}{DB}=\frac{AC}{DA}=\frac{BC}{BA}$$ and from here we obtain:
$$AB^2=BC\cdot BD,$$ 
$$\frac{\sqrt{BC\cdot BD}}{BD}=\frac{AC}{AD},$$ which is
$$AC^2\cdot BD=AD^2\cdot BC,$$
which is exactly that you want to get.

Comment: Thanks sir!!! Just what I wanted.

Comment: @Sen47 You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I must be missing something, because it seems to me like C can still be made arbitrarily close to A, making AC arbitrarily close to zero, while neither AD nor BC approach zero.  Does my picture represent a possible scenario for this problem, or am I missing something?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObtrA.jpg)

Comment: This is certainly possible... Actually the problem is from Sharygin's Problem Book and a lot of questions there are ambiguously worded... So I can't help you further. But thanks for the effort. I'll wait for more answers.